# Button not working in multi-page application

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created 2 buttons. The second  button should go to  NewFile.html but it isn't working. my index.html main file consist of div tag inside it created 2 buttons and with id ForNext for one of the button.

main.js

```
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};
var path = "";

function wlCommonInit(){
$('#ForDeviceProp').click(deviceProp);
$('#ForNext').click(nextMethod);
}
function nextMethod() {

$("#ForNext").load(path + "pages/NewFile.html", function(){
$.getScript(path + "js/NewPage.js", function() {
          if (currentPage.init) {
            currentPage.init();
         }
    });
});

}
```

Newpage.js

```
currentPage = {};
currentPage.init = function(){
WL.Logger.debug("NewFile :: init");
};
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried using a debugger? You should add your `.html` also...

Comment: Provide your full implementation - upload the MobileFirst project to dropbox or google drive.

Comment: below is my index.html file

Comment: You are basing your code on the multipage sample application, but your code above is missing code from the same sample, as such it is not clear what it is that you are really doing. **provide your sample for debugging*.

Comment: @IdanAdar no sir i am modifyingl the ui controls sample that have been given and added addtional button in index.html which should go to another html on clicking it .My doubt is whether ibm mobile first allows only multipage through <div> tag

Comment: Provide your project for debugging, because you did not supply enough code to help you. What do you not understand in that?

Comment: @IdanAdar https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_un-SB-HiYqWHRRMTZvZTZhV1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IdanAdar their sir help please ??

Answer (score 0):

There are all sort of issues, but the main ones are the following:

1. In nextMethod() You are trying to load NewFile.html into the ID of your button. That won't work: `$("#ForNext").load("pages/NewFile.html", function(){`

It needs to be loaded into the `pagePort` DIV. Replace "ForNext" with "pagePort".

2. In  `bba=    WL.Client.getEnvironmen();`, you are missing the "t" in ".getEnvironment".

Comment: why we cant load NewFile.html into the id of my button??

Comment: Because it's a button! You cannot load HTML into a button.

Comment: You are obviously implementing this based on the multipage sample application - same code was copy/pasted. Follow the multipage application tutorial and sample.