# Multipage application in Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Do i need to insert external html element into parent element only through  tag in parent html because i have created a button in parent html and not able to open the external html thorugh the button click??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button not working in multi-page application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986848/button-not-working-in-multi-page-application)

Answer (score 0):

As already explained to you in the original question, here: [Button not working in multi-page application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986848/button-not-working-in-multi-page-application)... this fails because you were attempting to `.load` the contents of an .html file into a HTML *button* (you were using the `ForNext` id). This is not possible. You do not load HTML into a button. The fix was to point to the `pagePort` id which belongs to a DIV. To a DIV you *can* load/append/replace HTML...